# Applying Effects on audio (e,g robot sound, big robot sound) in android

Tags: android, soundpool, audio-processing, soundeffect

I am using `SoundPool` to change the pitch of sound. A value of `1.0` means playback at the original frequency. A value of `2.0` means playback fast as with double speed, and a value of `0.5` means playback at half speed, but **I want to to change the pitch of sound without changing playing speed(frequency) of sound**.

How could I achieve that like I want to achieve **robot like sound** by setting pitch rate to `0.5` etc but playing speed is too slow.

Any help will highly appreciated!

Comment: try this `.jar` http://web.archive.org/web/20081103052639/http://www.adetorres.com/keychanger/KeyChangerReadme.html

Comment: native android does not have this functionality, you'll need to research  audio signal processing and use libraries like @Hanzala recommended

Comment: https://github.com/google/oboe